# Gnome File "Extract Here" failed, but command line unzip works

Tags: gnome, unzip

Using Ubuntu 20.04.2, Gnome 3.36.8, all up-to-date (2021-03-07).

Download [SDK Platform-Tools for Linux](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools). Using the File app, right click, "Extract Here". The result is an empty directory named `platform-tools_r31.0.0-linux`.

Using command line `unzip platform-tools_r31.0.0-linux.zip` the zip was uncompressed successfully. Is it a bug in the File app?

Comment: Did you try to unzip a different file to see if it was just that one file, or did you just try that one file?

Comment: Repeat the same procedure with another zip work OK. Example: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/blueline-rq2a.210305.006-factory-b4a2f36e.zip
The puzzling thing is the File/right click/Extract Here seems not to be "universal" enough.

Comment: The reason I ask is that it sounds like a bug.